# Access all parent component functions from child component

Tags: angular

I'm creating a component, where I'll have 3 buttons `[ Edit, Cancel, Save ]`, when the user clicks the Edit Button, Save and Cancel button will appear, when clicking the Save Button, it will trigger a function from the parent component.

The problem is when I pass a function from the parent to the ESC component, it can't access other functions from the parent directive.

> Note the component will be used in as a global operation in different
>   components

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmyFjwhM6tPZXubTfeGA?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Code:

```
<div [hidden]="isEdit">
      <button (click)="toggleEdit()">Edit</button>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!isEdit">
      <button (click)="runFunction(); toggleEdit()">Save</button>
      <button (click)="toggleEdit()">Cancel</button>
    </div>

export class EscComponent { 
    @Input() run: Function;

    runFunction() {
      console.log('Run Function')
      this.run()
    }

    isEdit = false;

    toggleEdit() {
      this.isEdit = !this.isEdit;
    }
}
```

Parent Component:

```
Component usage: <app-esc [run]="setName"></app-esc>


export class AppComponent { 
      name = 'Angular'; 

      setName() {
        this.setNameCd();
      }

      setNameCb() {
         this.name = 'Angular 2 asd';
      }
    }
```

Comment: Reverse your thinking, use `@Output` for this specific purpose.

Comment: How do you mean? Im not sure if this can be done with output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Harry Ninh is right, you should use the decorator `@Output` or create a specific service. Here is a working Plunker with @output:

http://plnkr.co/edit/wadCAyW5kah0VjVR2m5B?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview

You have also a few typo in your original plunker, so you should review your code for others typos.

Here is how it works:

Parent listen to the output

```
<app-esc (endEditing)="setName($event)"></app-esc>
```

In child component, import @Output and EventEmitter

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Initiate the output:

```
@Output() endEditing = new EventEmitter();
```

Emit the event in relevant function

```
this.endEditing.emit();
```

Comment: Lol your answer works, i wrote same plunker as yours but its not working. Can you tell me what am i doing wrong ? 
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmyFjwhM6tPZXubTfeGA?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview

Comment: did you correct all your typos ? for example `this.setNameCd();` to `this.setNameCb();`?

Comment: OMG b and d look so similar, i couldnt get what im doing wrong, thanks :)